# Login .bat script in Windows XP user to run with admin rights

Tags: windows, batch-file, net-use

```
if exist C:\Windows\System32\CCM\CcmExec.exe (
    net use /del Z:
) else (
    net use z: \\c-svsccm01\SMS_CMB\Client 
    start /d "Z:\" CCMSetup.exe
)
```

This is a .bat file I created to run a `.exe` file in the mapped location "Z:\". It runs perfectly in the administrator account but not in the user account (which doesn't have admin rights to install an `.exe` file).

In the user account, the mapping can be created and deleted but running the `CCMSetup.exe` doesn't work.

How can I run this `CCMSetup.exe` with admin rights in the user account?

Comment: Does the user have full permissions to the folder?

Comment: Use te `RUNAS` tool to run *CCMSetup.exe* as administrator.